# Button is disabled after hitting 'back' button, even though user information is still stored in required fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am currently working on a sign up page and I have implemented React Routers to 'continue' with the sign up process once certain criteria is met. Once a user enters sign in information on the first page/ part of the sign up process, the next page will ask for them to "Create" their profile. However, when the user lands on the second page/ part to create their profile and hit the "back" button, the button 'Continue" from the first page/ part of the sign up process is disabled when it should be enabled because the past information they entered is still present in the required fields. How do I make the button enabled if the user's information is still present in required fields if the user hits the back button?

Here is the full code in question:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createUsers } from "../../reducers/usersReducer";
import userInformation from "../../services/userInformation";
import moment from 'moment'
import {
  Routes, Route, Link, useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom"

import { VectorIllustration } from "./VectorIllustration"
import '../../style-sheets/SignUpForm.css'
import CountryOfOrigin from "./CountryOfOrigin";

import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { DesktopDatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { Button, InputAdornment, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import AccountBoxSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountBoxSharp';
import AlternateEmailSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AlternateEmailSharp';
import EmailSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmailSharp';
import LockSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockSharp';
import Dangerous from "@mui/icons-material/Dangerous";
import CheckCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle';


const SignUpForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector(state => state);
  const [usernameExists, setUsernameExists] = useState()
  const [emailExists, setEmailExists] = useState()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  console.log(state)

  const handleLoginRoute = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('hi')
  }

  const handleUsernameCheck = async (e) => {
    dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'username'))
    const checkIfUserExists = await userInformation.newUser(e.target.value, 'username')
    if (checkIfUserExists === 'Username is already taken') {
      setUsernameExists(true)
    } else {
      setUsernameExists(false)
    }
  }

  const handleEmailCheck = async (e) => {
    dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'email'))
    const checkIfEmailExists = await userInformation.newUser(e.target.value, 'email')
    if (checkIfEmailExists === 'Email is already in use') {
      setEmailExists(true)
    } else {
      setEmailExists(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="sign-up-page-container">
      <VectorIllustration />
      <div className="sign-up-form-container">
        <h1 className="sign-up-text">Sign Up</h1>
        <form onSubmit={() => navigate('/signup/1')}>

          {usernameExists ? <p className="users-username-input-warning-message">Username is already taken, please choose a different one</p> : ''}

          <TextField value={state.users?.username} required={true} className='users-username-input' label='Username' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                {usernameExists ? <AlternateEmailSharpIcon sx={{color: 'red'}}/> : <AlternateEmailSharpIcon color="primary"/>}
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              usernameExists ? <Dangerous sx={{color: 'red'}} /> : ''
            ),
            classes: {
              notchedOutline: usernameExists ? 'users-username-input-warning-message' : ''
            }
          }} InputLabelProps={{
            style: usernameExists ? {color: 'red'} : {}
          }} onChange={handleUsernameCheck} />

          <TextField value={state.users?.name} className="users-name-input" required={true} label='Name' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                <AccountBoxSharpIcon color="primary"/>
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }} onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'name'))}/>

          {emailExists ? <p className="users-email-input-warning-message">Email is already in use, please enter a different one</p> : ''}

          <TextField value={state.users?.email} className="users-email-input" required={true} label='Email' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                {emailExists ? <EmailSharpIcon sx={{ color: 'red'}}/> : <EmailSharpIcon color="primary"/>}
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment>
                {emailExists ? <Dangerous sx={{ color: 'red' }}/> : ''}
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            classes: {
              notchedOutline: emailExists ? 'users-email-input-warning-message' : ''
            }
          }} InputLabelProps={{
            style: emailExists ? {color: 'red'} : {}
          }} onChange={handleEmailCheck}/>

          <TextField value={state.users?.password} className="users-password-input" required={true} label='Password' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                <LockSharpIcon color="primary"/>
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment>
                {state.users.password && state.users.password.length >= 12 ? <CheckCircleIcon color="success" /> : 'The password must be at least 12 characters long!'}
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }} onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'password'))}/>

          <TextField value={state.users?.confirmationPassword} className="users-confirmation-password-input" required={true} label='Confirm Password' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                <LockSharpIcon color="primary"/>
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                {state.users.password === state.users.confirmationPassword ? <CheckCircleIcon color="success"/> : <Dangerous sx={{ color: 'red' }}/>}
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }} onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'confirmationPassword'))}/>

          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DesktopDatePicker minDate={moment('01/01/1900').toDate()} renderInput={(params) => <TextField required={true} {...params} className='users-date-of-birth-input' sx={{ svg: {color: '#1976d2'}}} onChange={(e) => {
              dispatch(createUsers(new Date([...e.currentTarget.value].reverse().join(''))), 'dateOfBirth')}} value={state.users?.dateOfBirth}/>} inputFormat='MM/dd/yyyy' value={state.users.dateOfBirth} onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e, 'dateOfBirth'))} label='Date of birth' InputAdornmentProps={{ position: 'start' }} InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment>
                  {state.users.dateOfBirth && state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() + 18 > (new Date()).getFullYear() ? 'Must be 18 years or older to register' : ''}
                </InputAdornment>
              )
            }} />
          </LocalizationProvider>

          <CountryOfOrigin state={state}/>

          <Button className="submit-button" sx={{ color: 'white' }} type="submit" disabled={state.users.password && state.users.password.length >= 12 && usernameExists === false && emailExists === false && state.users.password === state.users.confirmationPassword && state.users.username && state.users.name && state.users.location && state.users.dateOfBirth && state.users.dateOfBirth !== 'Invalid Date' && state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() + 18 <= (new Date()).getFullYear() && state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() >= 1900 && state.users.email ? false : true} >Continue</Button>
          <p className="already-have-an-account-text">Already have an account? <b className="bolded-log-in-link" onClick={handleLoginRoute}>Log in</b></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

Here is the specific lines of code that I believe is causing the issue, the Button component at the bottom:

```
<Button className="submit-button" sx={{ color: 'white' }} type="submit" disabled={state.users.password && state.users.password.length >= 12 && usernameExists === false && emailExists === false && state.users.password === state.users.confirmationPassword && state.users.username && state.users.name && state.users.location && state.users.dateOfBirth && state.users.dateOfBirth !== 'Invalid Date' && state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() + 18 <= (new Date()).getFullYear() && state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() >= 1900 && state.users.email ? false : true} >Continue</Button>
```

Here is a picture of the sign up page part 1 (After user enters in all required fields):
[image: First part]

Here is a picture of the second page after user hits 'continue':
[image: Second part]

Here is a picture of what the button looks like when the user hits the back button, the button is disabled even though the required fields are still left intact:
[image: Part 3]

**UPDATE (07/30/2022):**
By @AttemptedMastery's request, here is what the console.log looks like for the redux state whenever I hit the back button to return back to the sign up page... I do not believe the `undefined` key with an `'Invalid Date'` is giving me the issue...

[image: Console.log]

Comment: Can you please add this on sandboxcode or share on github ? Then I'll figure out What's gonna happen ?

Comment: @UmarIjaz

Github: https://github.com/UvZoomE/Find-A-Sponsor

Comment: Can you show me what your state object looks like when you go back?  console.log it

Comment: @AttemptedMastery

```
{users: {…}}
users:
Invalidation message: "Invalid Date"
confirmationPassword: "gggggggggggg"
dateOfBirth: Tue Jul 27 2004 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
[[Prototype]]: Object
email: "ggggggfg"
location: "Barbados"
name: "gggggfg"
password: "gggggggggggg"
username: "gggggfg"
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Am I seeing this right or is your date state not persisting correctly? You seem to be checking for an "Invalid Date" message, which is what your state shows - could this be why your button is disabled?  It would be better to copy the whole state from console.log and display it within your a original post.

Comment: the invalid date is saved in a different key so i dont think it should matter, the date is persisted through ```dateOfBirth```

Comment: So ````dateOfBirth```` is not ````state.users.dateOfBirth !== 'Invalid Date'````?  Okay, just checking the obvious.  EDIT: Ah, I see ````dateOfBirth```` property

Comment: I removed that line of code, does not seem to do anything for me...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246826/discussion-between-attemptedmastery-and-supracoder).

Comment: I am still requiring assistance on this matter if anyone is looking at this, thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell without more debugging info. Try running `console.log(state.users.password, state.users.password.length >= 12, usernameExists === false, emailExists === false, state.users.password === state.users.confirmationPassword, state.users.username, state.users.name, state.users.location, state.users.dateOfBirth, state.users.dateOfBirth !== 'Invalid Date', state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() + 18 <= (new Date()).getFullYear(), state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() >= 1900, state.users.email ? false : true)` And see what you get. I believe that one of these is truthy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Konrad Linkowski's request to console.log

```
console.log(state.users.password, state.users.password.length >= 12, usernameExists === false, emailExists === false, state.users.password === state.users.confirmationPassword, state.users.username, state.users.name, state.users.location, state.users.dateOfBirth, state.users.dateOfBirth !== 'Invalid Date', state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() + 18 <= (new Date()).getFullYear(), state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() >= 1900, state.users.email ? false : true)
```

I was able to identify the problem, it looks like using `state` versus `redux` differs in how each item is stored. When I hit the back button, any variable that used `state` versus `redux` did not maintain it's original value after I pressed **Continue** away from that page, it kept a value of `true` for usernameExists and emailExists which would not let me continue in the sign up process. So, to maintain values across both pages, I used the redux `store` to maintain the values for `usernameExists` and `emailExists` and when I hit the **back** button, redux was able to maintain their original values before hitting **continue** thus allowing me to have a button that was not disabled... I basically got rid of `useState` and kept using `redux`

**Updated code**

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createUsers } from "../../reducers/usersReducer";
import userInformation from "../../services/userInformation";
import moment from 'moment'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import validator from 'validator'

import { VectorIllustration } from "./VectorIllustration"
import '../../style-sheets/SignUpForm.css'
import CountryOfOrigin from "./CountryOfOrigin";

import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { DesktopDatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { Button, InputAdornment, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import AccountBoxSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountBoxSharp';
import AlternateEmailSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AlternateEmailSharp';
import EmailSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmailSharp';
import LockSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockSharp';
import Dangerous from "@mui/icons-material/Dangerous";
import CheckCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle';


const SignUpForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector(state => state);
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleUsernameCheck = async (e) => {
    dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'username'))
    const checkIfUserExists = await userInformation.newUser(e.target.value, 'username')
    if (checkIfUserExists === 'Username is already taken') {
      dispatch(createUsers(true, 'usernameExists'))
    } else {
      dispatch(createUsers(false, 'usernameExists'))
    }
  }

  const handleEmailCheck = async (e) => {
    dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'email'))
    const checkIfEmailExists = await userInformation.newUser(e.target.value, 'email')
    if (checkIfEmailExists === 'Email is already in use') {
      dispatch(createUsers(true, 'emailExists'))
    } else {
      dispatch(createUsers(false, 'emailExists'))
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="sign-up-page-container">
      <VectorIllustration />
      <div className="sign-up-form-container">
        <h1 className="sign-up-text">Sign Up</h1>
        <form id="signup-handler" onSubmit={() => navigate('/signup/1')}>

          {state.users.usernameExists ? <p className="users-username-input-warning-message">Username is already taken, please choose a different one</p> : ''}

          <TextField value={state.users?.username} required={true} className='users-username-input' label='Username' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                {state.users.usernameExists ? <AlternateEmailSharpIcon sx={{color: 'red'}}/> : <AlternateEmailSharpIcon color="primary"/>}
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              state.users.usernameExists ? <Dangerous sx={{color: 'red'}} /> : ''
            ),
            classes: {
              notchedOutline: state.users.usernameExists ? 'users-username-input-warning-message' : ''
            }
          }} InputLabelProps={{
            style: state.users.usernameExists ? {color: 'red'} : {}
          }} onChange={handleUsernameCheck} />

          <TextField value={state.users?.name} className="users-name-input" required={true} label='Name' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                <AccountBoxSharpIcon color="primary"/>
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }} onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'name'))}/>

          {state.users.emailExists ? <p className="users-email-input-warning-message">Email is already in use, please enter a different one</p> : !state.users.email || !validator.isEmail(state.users.email) ? <p className="users-email-input-valid-email-message">Please enter a valid email address</p> : ''}

          <TextField value={state.users?.email} className="users-email-input" required={true} label='Email' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                {state.users.emailExists || (!state.users.email || !validator.isEmail(state.users.email)) ? <EmailSharpIcon sx={{ color: 'red'}}/> : <EmailSharpIcon color="primary"/>}
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment>
                {state.users.emailExists || (!state.users.email || !validator.isEmail(state.users.email))  ? <Dangerous sx={{ color: 'red' }}/> : ''}
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            classes: {
              notchedOutline: state.user?.emailExists ? 'users-email-input-warning-message' : !state.users.email || !validator.isEmail(state.users.email) ? 'users-email-input-valid-email-message' : ''
            }
          }} InputLabelProps={{
            style: state.users.emailExists || (!state.users.email || !validator.isEmail(state.users.email)) ? {color: 'red'} : {}
          }} onChange={handleEmailCheck}/>

          <TextField value={state.users?.password} className="users-password-input" required={true} label='Password' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                <LockSharpIcon color="primary"/>
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment>
                {state.users.password && state.users.password.length >= 12 ? <CheckCircleIcon color="success" /> : 'The password must be at least 12 characters long!'}
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }} onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'password'))}/>

          <TextField value={state.users?.confirmationPassword} className="users-confirmation-password-input" required={true} label='Confirm Password' InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='start'>
                <LockSharpIcon color="primary"/>
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                {state.users.confirmationPassword?.length >= 12 && state.users.confirmationPassword && state.users.password === state.users.confirmationPassword ? <CheckCircleIcon color="success"/> : <Dangerous sx={{ color: 'red' }}/>}
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }} onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'confirmationPassword'))}/>

          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DesktopDatePicker minDate={moment('01/01/1900').toDate()} renderInput={(params) => <TextField required={true} {...params} className='users-date-of-birth-input' sx={{ svg: {color: '#1976d2'}}} onChange={(e) => {
              dispatch(createUsers(new Date([...e.currentTarget.value].reverse().join(''))), 'dateOfBirth')}} value={state.users?.dateOfBirth}/>} inputFormat='MM/dd/yyyy' value={state.users.dateOfBirth} onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e, 'dateOfBirth'))} label='Date of birth' InputAdornmentProps={{ position: 'start' }} InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment>
                  {state.users.dateOfBirth && state.users.dateOfBirth.getFullYear() + 18 > (new Date()).getFullYear() ? 'Must be 18 years or older to register' : ''}
                </InputAdornment>
              )
            }} />
          </LocalizationProvider>

          <CountryOfOrigin state={state}/>
          </form>
          <Button form='signup-handler' className="submit-button" sx={{ color: 'white' }} type="submit" disabled={state.users.password?.length >= 12 && state.users.usernameExists === false && state.users.emailExists === false && state.users.password === state.users.confirmationPassword && state.users.dateOfBirth?.getFullYear() + 18 <= (new Date()).getFullYear() && state.users.dateOfBirth?.getFullYear() >= 1900 && validator.isEmail(state.users.email) ? false : true} >Continue</Button> {/*Stack overflow submitted for reasoning behind why button gets disabled when I hit back button to return back to this page and everything is still filled out.*/}
          <p className="already-have-an-account-text">Already have an account? <Link className="bolded-log-in-link" to='/'>Log in</Link></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

Comment: The component probably unmounted which caused the state to disappear. I'm glad you managed to fix this :)